# Select row in Pandas dataframe where a column value is max based on a function of two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, max

I have the following dataframe.

```
data = {'Name': ["Babu", "Shyam", "Raju", "Anuradha", "Kabira"],
       'Age': [60, 35, 32, 31, 37],
       'Income': [20000, 10000, 8000, 12000, 5000],
       'Stupidity Level': [80, 40, 60, 20, 70],
       'Expenses': [15000,8000,7000,9000,4000]
       }

index = ["Paresh Rawal", "Suniel Shetty", "Akshay Kumar","Tabu", "Gulshan Grover"]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index)
```

[image]

I am trying to find out a row (person) who saves maximum amount every month.

```
savings = df["Income"] - df["Expenses"]
savings.max()
5000
```

In this case, it should return the first row whose savings is maximum (5000). But I am trying to this without actually creating a new column for savings. So want to do something like

```
df[savings.max()] # should return the row with maximum savings. 
df[(df["Income"] - df["Expenses"]).max()]
```

But of course, none of this isn't working. Not sure of the correct synatax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html):

```
df.loc[df["Income"].sub(df["Expenses"]).idxmax()]
```

output:

```
Name                Babu
Age                   60
Income             20000
Stupidity Level       80
Expenses           15000
Name: Paresh Rawal, dtype: object
```

###### all max

```
s = df["Income"].sub(df["Expenses"])

out = df[s.eq(s.max())]
```

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of the function idxmax. Although I wonder in the documentation of idxmax() why does it say "Return index of first occurrence of maximum over requested axis." Why say "first occurrence" instead of just maximum over requested axis.

Comment: There can be several times the maximum ;)